# Crontab with WiringPi

Tags: gpio, cron, wiringpi

I want to change pin state at certain time with Crontab.
I tried to use this command: `7 0 * * * /usr/bin/gpio -g write 0 0` 
but it returns me this error: `bash: 7: command not found`
I also tried: `7 0 * * * /home/pi/test.sh`
but it gives me: `bash: 7: command not found`
test.sh files has only on line with this command: `gpio write 0 0`
I used `sudo chmod +x /home/pi/test.sh` before

EDIT 1:
`crontab -l` return `no crontab for pi`

Comment: You have a malformed crontab.  Please edit your questions and include the full result of `crontab -l`.

Comment: That is not a command! That is an entry in crontab. See https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

Comment: You have asked a similar question at [Crontab not executing php scripts](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/107526/79866). Do you also found a solution for this question here? If so please make an answer and accept it after two days.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply used `7 0 * * * gpio write 0 0` as my crontab "command"